# Link Toast to custom css file

Tags: ionic-framework, width, toast

I'm new to `Ionic`. I'm trying to change the width of a toast.
It is not working and keeps displaying the default toast!
I created a css file called `toast.css` in `/theme/custom/`

```
 . {
  width : 20px;
}
```

Method Looks like so:

```
toasterExe(text : string) {
const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: text,
  position: "top",
  duration: 3000,
  cssClass: "../../theme/custom/toast.css"
});
toast.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in **variables.scss**

add this line

```
$toast-width:80%
```

Comment: Um i didn't want to change the overall size of toasts. Just in the method